# Why the following Eclipse related files cannot be deleted?

Tags: eclipse

I understand that the best way to delete something on any linux distro, is to use the "locate" command and then start to delete all the folders and files shown in its output (in order to make sure that ALL related files are indeed deleted).

I did the same for Eclipse. However, I can`t delete the following remaining files:

```
VirtualBox:/usr/share/app-install/desktop$ locate eclipse
/home/qwerty/.eclipse
/home/qwerty/Downloads/eclipse
/home/qwerty/Downloads/eclipse-platform-4.4.2-linux-gtk.tar.gz
/opt/eclipse
/usr/local/bin/eclipse
/usr/local/nginx/html/phpcode/.settings/org.eclipse.php.core.prefs
/usr/local/nginx/html/phpcode/.settings/org.eclipse.php.debug.core.Debug_Process_Preferences.prefs
/usr/local/nginx/html/phpcode/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
/usr/local/nginx/html/phpcode/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
/usr/local/nginx/html/phpcode/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/eclipse-platform:eclipse.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/redeclipse:redeclipse.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/eclipse.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/redeclipse.png
/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
/usr/share/icons/lubuntu/apps/16/eclipse.svg
/usr/share/icons/lubuntu/apps/22/eclipse.svg
/usr/share/icons/lubuntu/apps/24/eclipse.svg
/usr/share/icons/lubuntu/apps/48/eclipse.svg
/usr/share/xml/docbook/stylesheet/docbook-xsl/eclipse
VirtualBox:/usr/share/app-install/desktop$
```

Can someone please clarify why?

Thanks,

Qwerty

Comment: What is the error message you get, when you try to delete those files?

Comment: There is no error message. I just get the prompt back.

Comment: How do you delete the file? `rm` command? Did you try `sudo rm`?

Comment: Yes. I tried with sudo, but still they are not deleted.

Comment: Did you check the rights if those files? Can you change them? Maybe the problem is related to VirtualBox?